# How to convert a plug into a GPIO pin

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I just got a new raspberry pi and set it up yesterday. And I have heard of people connecting their lamps and such to the raspberry pi and turning it on or off algorithmically. I was wondering how I could plug in my lamp to my raspberry pi using a basic plug on the lamp and somehow converting it to GPIO formatr.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's related to electrical engineering site.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of lamp is it?

If it's a lamp that plugs in directly into the main you could use a magnetic relay to turn it on/off.

If it's a light that uses DC after passing through a step-down transformer and a rectifier you could use a MOSFET in line to turn it on/off.